# How to find index and max value for overlapping numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy Array with the same SHAPEs. One with values and one with "zones". I need to find max value and index of the value in valuearr which overlap zone 3 in zonearr:

```
import numpy as np
valuearr = np.array([[10,11,12,13],
                     [21,22,23,24],
                     [31,32,33,34],
                     [41,42,43,44]])

zonearr = np.array([ [0,0,1,1],
                     [0,0,1,1],
                     [3,3,0,0],
                     [3,3,0,0]])
```

Im trying:

```
valuearr[np.argwhere(zonearr==3)].max()
44
```

When it should be 42.

To get index i try

```
ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(valuearr[np.argwhere(zonearr==3)], axis=None), valuearr.shape)
```

Which of course doesnt work since max value is not 44 and also give error:

> builtins.ValueError: index 19 is out of bounds for array with size 16

Comment: For me `print(valuearr[zonearr==3].max())` gives `42`. Maybe make sure that your `zonearr` is of `dtype=np.int`.

Comment: @ThomasKühn, zonearr.dtype give int32

Comment: Oh, I think I only start to understand now: did you also want to find the correct index of the value 42?

Comment: Yes that is giving me 42 which is correct. Yes i also want the index of max value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
np.max(valuearr[np.where(zonearr==3)])
```

It fetches the indices of the elements from `zonearr`, where the value equals to '3'. Followed by, obtaining the maximum element from `valuearr` through the obtained indices.

To obtain the index of the element 42(as per your example), please use the below code:

```
np.argwhere(valuearr==np.max(valuearr[np.where(zonearr==3)]))
```

Comment: I don't see any differences in the results. But, just the differences in the approach used.

Comment: Simpler way: `maxval=valuearr[zonearr==3].max()` followed by `index=index=np.argwhere(valuearr==maxval)`

Comment: I Think that might find index of larger max values in other zones than 3. (my example data is not representing the real data)

Comment: @BERA, please look at the below solution, i.e, using a masked array, which works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a masked array to do what you want.

With:

```
import numpy as np
valuearr = np.array([[10,11,12,13],
                     [21,22,23,24],
                     [31,32,33,34],
                     [41,42,43,44]])

zonearr = np.array([ [0,0,1,1],
                     [0,0,1,1],
                     [3,3,0,0],
                     [3,3,0,0]], dtype=np.int)
```

First mask out all the values where `zonearr` is not equal to 3:

```
masked = np.ma.masked_array(valuearr, mask = (zonearr!=3))
```

Then find the position of the maximum value with `argmax`:

```
idx_1d = np.argmax(masked)
```

Finally, convert it into a 2d index:

```
idx_2d = np.unravel_index(idx_1d, valuearr.shape)
```

and print:

```
print(idx_2d, valuearr[idx_2d])
```

which gives:

```
(3, 1) 42
```

Comment: @BERA, please check this solution, it works perfectly.